# LightGbm in r 3.5.2

Tags: r, lightgbm

I am trying to install Lightgbm library in r 3.5.2.after millions of try i can do so. if anyone know how to install it?

I have try these methods to install lightgbm but always an error occur of such type.

1.

> Error in i.p(...) : 
>     (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/MUHAMM~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4EX73g/file7d81a401a17/lightgbm_2.2.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
>     skipping pax global extended headers
>   2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
>     skipping pax global extended headers

2.

> Error in lgb.dl(commit = "master", compiler = "vs", repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM",  : 
>     could not find function "lgb.dl"

```
#1
install.packages('devtools')
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lightgbm/lightgbm_3.5.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, contriburl=NULL, type="source")

#2 
download.file("https://github.com/hadley/lightgbm/archive/master.zip", destfile = "lightgbm.zip")

#3
lgb.dl(commit = "master",libdll = "C:\\xgboost\\LightGBM\\windows\\x64\\DLL\\lib_lightgbm.dll",
  # repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM",cores = 2)


#4 
lgb.dl(commit = "master", libdll = "C:\\LightGBM\\windows\\x64\\DLL\\lib_lightgbm.dll", # YOUR PRECOMPILED DLL
   #repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM")
```

> Error in lgb.dl(commit = "master", compiler = "vs", repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM",  : 
>     could not find function "lgb.dl"

```
#5
lgb.dl(commit = "master", compiler = "vs", # Remove this for MinGW + GPU installation repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM", use_gpu = TRUE)

#6
lgb.dl(commit = "master", compiler = "vs", # Remove this for MinGW + GPU installation repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM",use_gpu = TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you meet all the package requirements? "Preparation
You need to install git and CMake first.

Note: 32-bit R/Rtools is not supported.

Windows Preparation
Installing Rtools is mandatory, and only support the 64-bit version. It requires to add to PATH the Rtools MinGW64 folder, if it was not done automatically during installation."

Comment: I have install git & CMake. I have 64 bit R/Rtools. Now i have no idea how to add path to the Rtools MinGW64 folder.

Comment: Have you searched SO with the strategy: `[r] add path to the Rtools MinGW64`. I'm not a Windoze user (at least not in the last 5 years) but when I did that I got information that appeared useful.

Comment: I am running into same problem, have you been able to figure out?

Comment: Rana Usman till now i am not successful to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`{lgbl.dl}` was originally created to make installing `{lightgbm}` easier, since `{lightgbm}` had a difficult-to-use installation process.

That package has not kept up with changes in LightGBM, and is no longer necessary to install the R package on Windows, as the original question here mentions.

`{lightgbm}` is now [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lightgbm/index.html). Run this R code to install it.

```r
install.packages("lightgbm", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```